# Any suggestions to match and extract the pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match something like this

```
$(string).not(string).not(string)
```

The `not(string)` can repeat zero or more times, after `$(string)`.
Note that the string can be whatever things, except nested `not(string)`.

I used the regular expression `(\\$\\((.*)\\))((\\.not\\((.*?)\\))*?)(?!(\\.not))`, I think the `*?` is to non-greedily match any number of sequence of `not(string)`, and use the lookahead to stop the match that is not `not(string)`, so that I can extract only the part that I want.

However, when I tested on the input like

```
$(string).not(string).not(string).append(string)
```

the `group(0)` returns the whole string, which I only need `$(string).not(string).not(string)`.

Obviously I still miss something or misuse of anything, any suggestions?

Comment: "*Note that the string can be whatever things*" so is input like `$(string).not(".not(foo)").not(string)` possible?

Comment: Do you just want to validate, or do you need to process each `.not(...)` ?

Comment: "*the group(0) returns the whole string, which I only need `$(string).not(string).not(string)`.*" is little confusing. What you need and how is your input look like?

Comment: @Pshemo modified to say "..whatever things except nested not(string)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (escaped for java):

```
(\\$\\(string\\)(?:(?:\\.not\(.*?\\))+))
```

It should capture just the part that you are after. You [can test it out](https://regex101.com/r/tC5nZ9/1) (unescaped for java though)

Comment: Awesome! It works. And thanks for the link, which explains well. and the final expression I used is `(\\$\\((.*?)\\)(?:(?:\\.not\\((.*?)\\))*))` :)

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that parenthesis are not nested, you can write something like this:

```
string p = "\\$\\([^)]*\\)(?:\\.not\\([^)]*\\))*";
```

Not need to add a lookahead since the non-capturing group has a greedy quantifier (so the group is repeated as possible).

if what you called `string` in your question may be a quoted string with parenthesis inside like in Pshemo example: `$(string).not(".not(foo)").not(string)`, you can replace each `[^)]*` with `(?:\\s*\"[^\"]*\"\\s*|[^)]*)` to ignore characters inside quoted parts.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)), "group zero denotes the entire pattern". Use `group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\$\([\w ]+\))(\.not\([\w ]+\))*
```

This will also work, it would give you two groups, One consisting of the word with $ sign, another would give you the set of all ".not" strings.

Please note: You might have to add escape characters for java.